# based on the split count I need to color the row with different color

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub test()

Dim MyCell As Range, i As Long

Dim SelectedRange As Range
Set SelectedRange = Application.InputBox("Select Range", Type:=8)

Dim SplitRow As Long
SplitRow = Application.InputBox("Split Row Num", Type:=1)

Dim FormatRange As Long
FormatRange = SelectedRange.Rows.Count / SplitRow

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each MyCell In SelectedRange
        If i < FormatRange Then
            MyCell.Interior.Color = vbRed
            i = i + 1
        Else
            MyCell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
    Next MyCell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Okay? Thanks for including code, but can you outline the issue you're having? Are you getting errors? Incorrect output? What are your screenshots?

Comment: my code only consist of 2 different color , if my FormatRange = 3 or more than 3 i need different color or more than that !!

Comment: Remove the `macros` tag.  If you are unsure, read the tag info associated with [macros](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info).

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()
    Dim selectedRange As Range, splitRow As Long, formatRange As Long, i As Long

    Set selectedRange = Application.InputBox("Select Range", Type:=8)
    splitRow = Application.InputBox("Split Row Num", Type:=1)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With selectedRange
        formatRange = .Rows.Count / splitRow
        For i = 1 To .Rows.Count Step formatRange
            .Cells(i, 1).Resize(formatRange, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = i / formatRange + 3
        Next i
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: i need one more help !  Range("1:1").Find(what:="Reporting Manager").Select
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_owssvr.dll_1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, _
        Criteria1:=Array("prabhakb", "prvs", "smano", "jseas"), Operator:=xlFilterValues   , i need to get these name in the input box because these name changes according to the need so i have to change the code all the time instead of that an input box will be useful . Note there will be more than 5 name to filter . can u help ?!